# Is there a way to open a new page from a clicking on an shape in a drawn grid, in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am attempting to make a grid of items that you can click on and go to the product page(or whatever) but there is little documentation on using drawn shapes as a button. I assume there is a way to use open on click which I was testing out with changing the color of the shape. I am using flutter and am pretty new to the whole scene. If I could get any advice or help that would be great here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(HexagonGridDemo());
}

class HexagonGridDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  final grid = HexagonGrid();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Hexagon Grid Demo'),
        ),
        body: Container(//This is where you can shrink size of grid
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
            grid.initialize(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight);
            return Listener(
              onPointerDown: (PointerEvent details) {
                handleClick(details);
              },
              child: Container(
                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                height: constraints.maxHeight,
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: grid,
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  handleClick(PointerEvent details) {
    var hexagon =
    grid.hexagons.firstWhere((hexagon) => determineClick(hexagon, details));
    hexagon.key.currentState.updateColor();
  }//handleClick end
  bool determineClick(HexagonPaint hexagon, PointerEvent details) {
    final RenderBox hexagonBox =
    hexagon.model.key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final result = BoxHitTestResult();
    Offset localClick = hexagonBox.globalToLocal(details.position);
    if (hexagonBox.hitTest(result, position: localClick)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

}//stateless widget section ends

class HexagonGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final GridInitializer gridInitializer = GridInitializer();
  final List<HexagonPaint> hexagons = new List();

  void initialize(final double screenWidth, final double screenHeight) {
    if (this.hexagons.isEmpty) {
      hexagons.addAll(gridInitializer.getHexagons(screenWidth, screenHeight));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: hexagons);
  }
}
class GridInitializer {
  static const int marginY = 5;//margin for spacing
  static const int marginX = 5;//margin for spacing
  static const int nrX = 6;
  static const int nrY = 9;
  double radius;
  double height;
  double screenWidth;
  double screenHeight;

  List<HexagonPaint> getHexagons(
      final double screenWidth, final double screenHeight) {
    var hexagons = new List<HexagonPaint>();
    this.screenWidth = screenWidth;
    this.screenHeight = screenHeight;
    radius = computeRadius(screenWidth, screenHeight);
    height = computeHeight(computeRadius(screenWidth, screenHeight));
    for (int x = 0; x < nrX; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < nrY; y++) {
        hexagons.add(HexagonPaint(HexagonModel(computeCenter(x, y), radius)));
      }
    }
    return hexagons;
  }

  static double computeRadius(double screenWidth, double screenHeight) {
    var maxWidth = (screenWidth - totalMarginX()) / (((nrX - 1) * 1.5) + 2);
    var maxHeight = 0.5 *
        (screenHeight - totalMarginY()) /
        (heightRatioOfRadius() * (nrY + 0.5));
    return math.min(maxWidth, maxHeight);
  }

  static double heightRatioOfRadius() =>
      math.cos(math.pi / HexagonPainter.SIDES_OF_HEXAGON);

  static double totalMarginY() => (nrY - 0.5) * marginY;

  static int totalMarginX() => (nrX - 1) * marginX;

  static double computeHeight(double radius) {
    return heightRatioOfRadius() * radius * 2;
  }

  Offset computeCenter(int x, int y) {
    var centerX = computeX(x);
    var centerY = computeY(x, y);
    return Offset(centerX, centerY);
  }

  computeY(int x, int y) {
    var centerY;
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
      centerY = y * height + y * marginY + height / 2;
    } else {
      centerY = y * height + (y + 0.5) * marginY + height;
    }
    double marginsVertical = computeEmptySpaceY() / 2;
    return centerY + marginsVertical;
  }

  double computeEmptySpaceY() {
    return screenHeight - ((nrY - 1) * height + 1.5 * height + totalMarginY());
  }

  double computeX(int x) {
    double marginsHorizontal = computeEmptySpaceX() / 2;
    return x * marginX + x * 1.5 * radius + radius + marginsHorizontal;
  }

  double computeEmptySpaceX() {
    return screenWidth -
        (totalMarginX() + (nrX - 1) * 1.5 * radius + 2 * radius);
  }
}

class HexagonModel {
  final Offset center;
  final double radius;
  final GlobalKey key = GlobalKey();
  bool clicked = false;
  HexagonModel(this.center, this.radius);
}

class HexagonPaint extends StatefulWidget {
  final HexagonModel model;
  final GlobalKey<_HexagonPaintState> key = GlobalKey<_HexagonPaintState>();
  HexagonPaint(this.model);

  @override
  _HexagonPaintState createState() => _HexagonPaintState();
}

class _HexagonPaintState extends State<HexagonPaint> {
  updateColor() {
    setState(() {
      widget.model.clicked = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      key: widget.model.key,
      painter: HexagonPainter(
          widget.model.center, widget.model.radius, widget.model.clicked),
      child: Container(),
    );
  }
}

class HexagonPainter extends CustomPainter {
  static const int SIDES_OF_HEXAGON = 6;
  final double radius;
  final Offset center;
  final bool clicked;

  HexagonPainter(this.center, this.radius, this.clicked);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()..color = clicked ? Colors.red : Colors.blue;
    Path path = createHexagonPath();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  Path createHexagonPath() {
    final path = Path();
    var angle = (math.pi * 2) / SIDES_OF_HEXAGON;
    Offset firstPoint = Offset(radius * math.cos(0.0), radius * math.sin(0.0));
    path.moveTo(firstPoint.dx + center.dx, firstPoint.dy + center.dy);
    for (int i = 1; i <= SIDES_OF_HEXAGON; i++) {
      double x = radius * math.cos(angle * i) + center.dx;
      double y = radius * math.sin(angle * i) + center.dy;
      path.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(HexagonPainter oldDelegate) =>
      oldDelegate.clicked != clicked;

  @override
  bool hitTest(Offset position) {
    final Path path = createHexagonPath();
    return path.contains(position);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So for the Question, i kind of get it but the Code is a little confusing for me.
From what i understand, you are returning a bunch of Hexagon Elements(sort of) in the GridView ... this being the case, this is the part i need you to focus on:

```
class _HexagonPaintState extends State<HexagonPaint> {
  updateColor() {
    setState(() {
      widget.model.clicked = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      key: widget.model.key,
      painter: HexagonPainter(
          widget.model.center, widget.model.radius, widget.model.clicked),
      child: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

This is The Selected Model on the click event. Before you return `CustomPaint()` widget, Wrap it in an `InkWell()` widget. The `InkWell()` widget makes its child widget and other children below clickable, you can even use it on deeper elements in your `HexagonPaintState()`. You then map the gesture call backs to your functions or routes like so:

```
return Inkwell(
    onTap: (){//function calls/routes go here},
    child: CustomPaint(
      key: widget.model.key,
      painter: HexagonPainter(
          widget.model.center, widget.model.radius, widget.model.clicked),
      child: Container(),
    );
);
```

Check more callbacks like on long click under InkWell. To do this, simply `crtl+LMB` on `Inkwell()`this will take you to the Library with further explanations.